# Chatbot server does not received pass thread control event from facebook page manager android app

Tags: facebook, facebook-chatbot

Currently, I use facebook LiveChat feature that allow my bot to passing thread control to page inbox so that user can talk to page owner directly if they want.

According to document (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/pass-thread-control#page_inbox)
when admin page done chatting with user they can push "DONE" button and page inbox will passing thread control back to bot.

After testing with page inbox from web browser, everything seems to work well. However, I found out that if I push "DONE" button from facebook page manager android mobile app, my bot doesn't receive thread control from page inbox. So user thread control will stuck with admin page inbox forever and they cannot resume chatting with my bot, until admin page press "DONE" in browser page inbox.

Did I done something incorrectly or it is the bug from facebook page manager mobile app?

Comment: Please open a bug report on this:

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: Here is the link to bug report [link](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/530756454006645)